Button on a page should be in focus during initialization
In the python file, I have declared a main window and 2 child pages. Class UserSetup & class CreateID both have set_button_focus function. When I remove the function from CreateID, only then it works in UserSetup. If I keep it in CreateID and load UserSetup. textbox01 is focused. In both instances, when the child page is loaded, I want the button to be focused.
class UserSetup(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent: "Setup"):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.parent: "Setup" = parent  # Store the parent reference
    self.window_width = 500
    self.window_height = 450
    self.assets_dir = "Assets"  # Assets directory
    self.temp_image_path = os.path.join(self.assets_dir, "TempProfile.png")
    self.profile_image_path = os.path.join(self.assets_dir, "ProfilePic.png")

    # Create the user setup label
    label01 = QLabel("USER SETUP", self)
    label01.setFont(QFont("Georgia", 25))  # Set font to Georgia, size 25
    label01.setStyleSheet("color: #FFDE59;")  # Set foreground color
    label01.adjustSize()  # Adjust the label size according to text width
    label01.move((self.window_width - label01.width()) // 2, 10)  # Horizontally center and position vertically 10px down

    # Create the horizontal line (QFrame)
    line = QFrame(self)
    line.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.HLine)  # Set the frame to be a horizontal line
    line.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D9D9D9;")  # Set line color
    line.setGeometry(0, label01.y() + label01.height() + 1, self.window_width, 1)  # Position the line 1px below the label

    # Load and position the profile image
    self.profile_image = QLabel(self)
    pixmap = QPixmap(self.temp_image_path)
    self.profile_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    self.profile_image.setScaledContents(True)  # Scale the image if necessary
    self.profile_image.resize(100, 100)  # Set label size
    self.profile_image.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #FFDE59;")
    self.profile_image.move((self.window_width - self.profile_image.width()) // 2, label01.y() + label01.height() + 20)
    self.profile_image.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))

    # Create label below profile pic
    self.label02 = QLabel("Please use a square image", self)
    self.label02.setFont(QFont("Calibri", 8))
    self.label02.setStyleSheet("color: #D9D9D9;")  # Set foreground color
    self.label02.adjustSize()  # Adjust the label size according to text width
    self.label02.move((self.window_width - self.label02.width()) // 2, self.profile_image.y() + self.profile_image.height() + 5)

    # Enable mouse press event for profile image
    self.profile_image.mousePressEvent = self.handle_profile_image_click

    #Create textbox01 with Enter Full Name
    self.textbox01 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox01.setPlaceholderText("Enter Full Name")  # Placeholder text
    self.textbox01.setFixedSize(250, 30)  # Set fixed size for textbox
    self.textbox01.setStyleSheet("""
                QLineEdit {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                    font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                }
            """)
    self.textbox01.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox01.move((self.window_width - self.textbox01.width()) // 2, self.profile_image.y() + self.profile_image.height() + 30)

    #Create textbox02 with Enter Sanganak ID
    self.textbox02 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox02.setPlaceholderText("Enter Sanganak ID")
    self.textbox02.setFixedSize(250, 30)
    self.textbox02.setStyleSheet("""
                        QLineEdit {
                            background-color: transparent;
                            color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                            border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                            font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                        }
                    """)
    self.textbox02.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox02.move((self.window_width - self.textbox02.width()) // 2, self.textbox01.y() + self.textbox01.height() + 10)

    # Create textbox03 with Enter E-Mail ID
    self.textbox03 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox03.setPlaceholderText("Enter E-Mail ID")
    self.textbox03.setFixedSize(250, 30)
    self.textbox03.setStyleSheet("""
                                QLineEdit {
                                    background-color: transparent;
                                    color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                                    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                                    font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                                }
                            """)
    self.textbox03.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox03.move((self.window_width - self.textbox03.width()) // 2, self.textbox02.y() + self.textbox02.height() + 10)

    # Create textbox04 with Enter Mobile Number
    self.textbox04 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox04.setPlaceholderText("Enter Mobile Number")
    self.textbox04.setFixedSize(250, 30)
    self.textbox04.setStyleSheet("""
                                        QLineEdit {
                                            background-color: transparent;
                                            color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                                            border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                                            font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                                        }
                                    """)
    self.textbox04.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox04.move((self.window_width - self.textbox04.width()) // 2, self.textbox03.y() + self.textbox03.height() + 10)
    # Connect returnPressed signal to launch_create_id
    self.textbox04.returnPressed.connect(self.launch_create_id)

    # Create the button
    self.submit_button = QPushButton("&Submit", self)
    self.submit_button.setFixedSize(150, 30)

    # Set button styles
    self.submit_button.setStyleSheet(
        """
        QPushButton {font-family: Calibri; font-size: 20px; color: #FFDE59; background-color: #162D2D; border: 1px solid #FFDE59; border-radius: 5px;}
        QPushButton:hover {background-color: #405C54; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFDE59; color: #FFDE59;}
        """
    )

    # Position the button (center horizontally, 65 pixels from bottom)
    self.submit_button.move((self.window_width - self.submit_button.width()) // 2, self.window_height - 65)

    # Set cursor change on hover
    self.submit_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))

    # Connect the button to the method
    self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.launch_create_id)

    # Set the keyboard shortcut (ALT+S)
    self.submit_button.setShortcut("Alt+S")

    # Use QTimer to delay setting focus to ensure all widgets are initialized
    QTimer.singleShot(0, self.set_usersetup_button_focus)

def set_usersetup_button_focus(self):
    # Clear focus from textbox01 and set focus to the submit button
    self.textbox01.clearFocus()
    self.submit_button.setFocus()
class CreateID(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent: "Setup"):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.window_width = 500
    self.window_height = 450
    self.assets_dir = "Assets"  # Assets directory
    self.temp_image_path = os.path.join(self.assets_dir, "TempProfile.png")
    self.profile_image_path = os.path.join(self.assets_dir, "ProfilePic.png")
    db_path = os.path.join(self.assets_dir, "Sanganak.db")

    # Create the CreateID label
    label01 = QLabel("CREATE ID", self)
    label01.setFont(QFont("Georgia", 25))  # Set font to Georgia, size 25
    label01.setStyleSheet("color: #FFDE59;")  # Set foreground color
    label01.adjustSize()  # Adjust the label size according to text width
    label01.move((self.window_width - label01.width()) // 2, 10)  # Horizontally center and position vertically 10px down

    # Create the horizontal line (QFrame)
    line = QFrame(self)
    line.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.HLine)  # Set the frame to be a horizontal line
    line.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D9D9D9;")  # Set line color
    line.setGeometry(0, label01.y() + label01.height() + 1, self.window_width, 1)  # Position the line 1px below the label
    # Load and position the profile image
    self.profile_image = QLabel(self)
    if os.path.exists(self.profile_image_path):  # Check if ProfilePic.png exists
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.profile_image_path)
    else:
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.temp_image_path)
    self.profile_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    self.profile_image.setScaledContents(True)  # Scale the image if necessary
    self.profile_image.resize(100, 100)  # Set label size
    self.profile_image.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #FFDE59;")
    self.profile_image.move((self.window_width - self.profile_image.width()) // 2, label01.y() + label01.height() + 20)

    # Query the database to get the first name
    first_name = "User"  # Default fallback if something goes wrong
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Fetch the FullName from the SetUp table
        cursor.execute("SELECT FullName FROM SetUp LIMIT 1")
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            full_name = result[0]
            # Extract the text before the first space
            first_name = full_name.split(" ")[0] if " " in full_name else full_name
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing database: {e}")

    # Create label below profile pic
    self.label02 = QLabel(f"Hello, {first_name}!", self)
    self.label02.setFont(QFont("Calibri", 8))
    self.label02.setStyleSheet("color: #FFDE59;")  # Set foreground color
    self.label02.adjustSize()  # Adjust the label size according to text width
    self.label02.move((self.window_width - self.label02.width()) // 2, self.profile_image.y() + self.profile_image.height() + 5)

    # Create textbox01 with Set User ID
    self.textbox01 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox01.setPlaceholderText("Set User ID")  # Placeholder text
    self.textbox01.setFixedSize(250, 30)  # Set fixed size for textbox
    self.textbox01.setStyleSheet("""
                        QLineEdit {
                            background-color: transparent;
                            color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                            border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                            font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                        }
                    """)
    self.textbox01.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox01.move((self.window_width - self.textbox01.width()) // 2, self.profile_image.y() + self.profile_image.height() + 30)

    # Create textbox02 with Set Password
    self.textbox02 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox02.setPlaceholderText("Set Password")
    self.textbox02.setFixedSize(250, 30)
    self.textbox02.setStyleSheet("""
                                QLineEdit {
                                    background-color: transparent;
                                    color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                                    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                                    font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                                }
                            """)
    self.textbox02.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox02.move((self.window_width - self.textbox02.width()) // 2, self.textbox01.y() + self.textbox01.height() + 10)

    # Create the button
    self.submit_button = QPushButton("&Submit", self)
    self.submit_button.setFixedSize(150, 30)
    # Set button styles
    self.submit_button.setStyleSheet(
        """
        QPushButton {font-family: Calibri; font-size: 20px; color: #FFDE59; background-color: #162D2D; border: 1px solid #FFDE59; border-radius: 5px;}
        QPushButton:hover {background-color: #405C54; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFDE59; color: #FFDE59;}
        """
    )
    # Position the button (center horizontally, 65 pixels from bottom)
    self.submit_button.move((self.window_width - self.submit_button.width()) // 2, self.window_height - 65)
    # Set cursor change on hover
    self.submit_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
    # Set the keyboard shortcut (ALT+S)
    self.submit_button.setShortcut("Alt+S")
    # Connect the button click signal to the parent's method
    self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.launch_security)
    # Use QTimer to delay setting focus to ensure all widgets are initialized
    QTimer.singleShot(0, self.set_createid_button_focus)

def set_createid_button_focus(self):
    # Clear focus from textbox01 and set focus to the submit button
    self.textbox01.clearFocus()
    self.submit_button.setFocus()


please provide a [mre]

Also: 1. ensure that you're properly formatting code (code blocks should begin and end with triple ticks (```) in separate lines), or with consistent indentation, and check the post preview before submitting; 2. fixed geometries are almost always discouraged, layout managers should be used instead.
